# Ionic 2 - Record with bluetooth headset

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, ionic2, cordova-plugins, microphone

I'm developping an application that aims to record speech using a bluetooth headset microphone. I'm using Ionic 2 with this environment :

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.4
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.2.0
System:

Node       : v6.10.0
OS         : Windows 10
npm        : 3.10.10
```

I'm using cordova-plugin-audioinput to record the audio. I've tried to change the audio input source type of the configuration to VOICE_COMMUNICATION, MIC and DEFAULT. However, it's still recording with the device's microphone.

On Android, I've seen that MediaRecorder is used. I've tried to set the audioinput source to VOICE_CALL after reading [it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#) but the app crashed.

Finally, I found this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco%28%29). I would like to know if there is any cordova plugin to do this? Is there a way to record audio from a bluetooth headset microphone using Ionic 2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello,Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately no. I don't think that is possible..

Comment: I find this appalling? Did you figure this out yet?

Comment: @Chris, can you please de-accept the answer and re-institute my bounty? His answer does not work

Comment: I'm no longer working on this project :/

Answer (score 3):

There's no cordova wrapper known for that purpose.
What you could do is controlling the device directly through AT commands.
Basically, what Android does if you follow this documentation :

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html

is sending AT commands to the Headphone through Serial Communication.
You could use https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial to send and read RAW buffer from the bluetooth headset. You could for example send an AT command which will start the microphone recording on your headset, then get the RAW audio from the received buffers, then with the help of others libraries transform the RAW data to mp3.

If you want to read more about Serial Communication over bluetooth and especially AT commands : http://www.spezial.cz/pdf/Serial_Port_Adapter_AT_Commands.pdf

Comment: This library you recommended works for AD2P and HFP? I thought  it would only apply for the SPP profile (serial port porfile)

Comment: Yes you're right, it's only for SPP. It will depend whether your headset support SPP or not (constructors may supports multiple profiles). But if you look closer at the sources of this plugin and the android documentation about bluetooth profiles (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) you're not far from what you're looking for. :) You'll need to tweek the plugin a bit for sure but it's the closest you'll get for AD2P/HFP profiles

Comment: This does not work for a bluetooth headset. Or maybe i dont understand. How am I supposed to know what the command is for initializing the microphone.

Comment: It is getting late, but i did notice some AT commands in this doc. will work on this more tomorrow thank you https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=41181#page50